# What is wrong with this a MySQL 5.6 procedure definition? Use a variable for table name

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, parameter, procedure-definition

Just can't understand why it's throwing this error?

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

```
drop procedure if exists dividir_tabla_por_usuario;

delimiter //
create procedure dividir_tabla_por_usuario(tabla varchar(100), columna_usuario varchar(100), columna_fecha varchar(100))
begin
  set @i = 0;
  set @q1 = concat('select count(*) from (select distinct ', columna_usuario ,' from ', tabla , ' order by ', columna_usuario ,' asc) as t1 into @c');
  prepare p1 from @q;
  execute p1;
while @i <= @c do
  set @r = 0;
  set @q2 = concat('select * from ', tabla , ' where ', columna_usuario ,' = (select ', columna_usuario ,' from (select @r:=@r +1 as ord, ', columna_usuario ,' from (select distinct ', columna_usuario ,' from ', tabla , 'order by ', columna_usuario ,' asc) as t2) as t3 where ord = ', @i ,' ) order by ', columna_fecha ,' asc limit 30000'); 
  prepare p2 from @q2;
  execute p2;
  set @i := @i + 1;
end while;
end//
delimiter ;

call dividir_tabla_por_usuario('mytable', 'mycolumn_1', 'mycolumn_2');
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this. You can't pass a table name as a variable

Comment: Inside block (between Begin and End) you must have all declare statments before all other instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typos, always typos.

Here is the final working code:

```
drop procedure if exists dividir_tabla_por_usuario;

delimiter //
create procedure dividir_tabla_por_usuario(tabla varchar(100), columna_usuario varchar(100), columna_fecha varchar(100))
begin
  set @i = 0;
  set @q1 = concat('select count(*) from (select distinct ', columna_usuario ,' from ', tabla , ' order by ', columna_usuario ,' asc) as t1 into @c');
  prepare p1 from @q1;
  execute p1;
while @i <= @c do
  set @r = 0;
  set @q2 = concat('(select distinct ', columna_usuario ,' from ', tabla , ' order by ', columna_usuario ,' asc) as t2)');
  set @q3 = concat('(select @r:=@r +1 as ord, ', columna_usuario ,' from ',@q2, ' as t3 where ord = ', @i ,' )');
  set @q4 = concat('(select ', columna_usuario ,' from ', @q3);
  set @q5 = concat('select * from ', tabla , ' where ', columna_usuario ,' = ', @q4 ,' order by ', columna_fecha ,' asc limit 30000'); 
  prepare p2 from @q5;
  execute p2;
  set @i := @i + 1;
end while;
end//
delimiter ;

call dividir_tabla_por_usuario('mytable', 'mycolumn1', 'mycolumn2');
```